# unknown group Error Amq4808 in wsmq

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-7

I Am using **Websphere 7.5**. Whenever I try to create an object authority record for queue managers, it shows the error `(unknown group AMQ4808)`. If anybody having solution for this please let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the group known to the OS?

Comment: yes i added the user id in the group still am getting error
i just started learning WSMQ for three days can i have your hangout contact to clearify my doubts?

Comment: If you added the user Id to the group after the queue manager first reported that it wan't in the group, then the queue manager will have cached that information. You need to either restart the queue manager or issue the MQSC command REFRESH SECURITY, to tell it to throw away its cache of OS security. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried this @MoragHughson but its not working

Comment: srikanthdece@gmail.com this is my mail id, If anybody can allocate time for me please ping me or give me your contact 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you supply some more information in your question to allow us to attempt to help you further. Please supply the full command you are issue to "create an object authority record", and the full error from the error log that is "(unknown group AMQ4808)". We don't have a lot to go on. Please also provide list of the user id and group from the OS that is causing the issue. And tell us what platform.